# Estimating a location of point C on a map based on the change in distance from AC to BC using the respective radii around point A and B

Tags: plane-geometry

I was just wondering, suppose your current location is A and you know a point C is ym away, if you know move to point B and B is consequently only xm away from C, (given ym>xm) could you approximate the location of C using two radii?

Comment: What are ym and xm?

Comment: Anyway, if you know where $A$ and $B$ are (on, say, a plane), and you know the distances of $C$ from both $A$ and $B$, then, yes, $C$ is one of the two intersection points of the appropriate circles centered at $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Are you still here, Liam?

Comment: Thank you seconding my assumption. I guess I'm going to stop using certain mobile applications then.

Comment: ym and xm are the appropriate distances.